# Formula for conditional variance for continuous random variable.

Tags: variance

I need to expand the conditional variance of continuous random variable as a sum of integrals. Here is my try:

$$D(Y|X)=E[Y^2|X] - [E(Y|X)]^2 + EY = \int_y y^2f(x|y)dy -\left(\int_y yf(x|y)\right)^2dy $$
But I know that the second term is incorrect / could be rewritten otherwise. Maybe somoene has an insight?

Comment: Where did you get this equation?  Why $\mu_y$ term? In any case the second term should not have $y^2$, only $y$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Ok, now I corrected the equation. Maybe you know how to rewrite / expand the second term?

Comment: tommik answer is correct.  You need to move $dy$ inside the square of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula of conditional variance is wrong...the correct one is the following

$$\mathbb{V}[Y|X=x]=\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X=x]-\mathbb{E}^2[Y|X=x]=$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}y^2f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy-\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_{Y|X}(y|x)dy \right]^2$$

There is nothing else to expand...